# passing input between multiple functions?

Tags: python

im currently trying to pass input between multiple functions. As of now im having an extremely hard time figuring out how to do it with my program. My program consists of 2 functions. main() will get the user input, remove all punctuation and capital() will take that output and turn it into all caps. However, when i call the function it only prints it fully capitalized rather than printing it first without the punctuation and then fully capitalized.

here is what ive tried. I set the space variable = to my main function so i can pass on the string thats produced from main. However im getting the error from above and feel my solution is extremely inefficient. if anyone has a way to do this without using a global constant or global variable please let me know. the was im trying to do this is with parameters but i am very confused as to why this is happening. thanks

````
punctuation = "!@#$%^&*():<>?{}[]`\/~"


def capital():
    space = main()
    string2 = ''
    for i in range(len(space)):
        if(space[i] >= 'a' and space[i] <= 'z'):
            string2 = string2 + chr((ord(space[i]) - 32))
        else:
            string2 = string2 + space[i]
    return string2



def main():
    user_string=input("Please enter a string: ")
    space  = ""
    for character in user_string:
        if character not in punctuation:
            space = space+character
    return space

print(capital())
print(main())
```
`
````

Comment: Maybe it's just a naming issue, but it seems odd for `capital` to be calling `main`, rather than `main` being solely the main entry point for your program.

Comment: If `capital` is really the entry point and it calls `main()` to get the initial input, then *it* should be printing the value of `space` before it returns the capitalized version, rather than you calling `main` explicitly to get *another* string.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this might be happening is because you are calling main() prior to assignment, which does not work on some versions of python if I remember correctly. You could update to a newer version, but a better way is to use parameters like you explained.

To make a parameter, you could have your `capital()` function take in a variable. To do this, simply write the name of the local variable (only usable inside the function) inside the parentheses:
`def capital(space):`
Then, all you need to do is run `capital()` and pass in `main()` as `space`:

```py
def capital(space):
    string2 = ''
    for i in range(len(space)):
        if(space[i] >= 'a' and space[i] <= 'z'):
            string2 = string2 + chr((ord(space[i]) - 32))
        else:
            string2 = string2 + space[i]
    return string2



def main():
    user_string=input("Please enter a string: ")
    space  = ""
    for character in user_string:
        if character not in punctuation:
            space = space+character
    return space

print(capital(main()))
```